# SOQL: mismatched character '<EOF>' expecting '''

Tags: soql

I have 1 field in my salesforce CRM 'Food & Beverage' & I want to access it using below query:

```
"SELECT id, FirstName, Status, FORMAT(LastModifiedDate) FROM LEAD where id != null and FirstName != null and  (Industry = 'Food & Beverage')  order by LastModifiedDate desc LIMIT 10"
```

But I'm getting below response:

> mismatched character '' expecting '''"

Does anyone has any idea?